# Error: invalid character in path File.ReadLine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried read a string from text file, line by line, but I get this error, see my code please. there is a another approach for read a string line by line, or one solution for this error? The file is saved in UTF8.

link for file content: https://shrib.com/#MHVN4JhCgKStecY7Q4ei

```
public Games RetornarGames(string arquivo)
{
    try
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        Games games = new Games();

        foreach (string linha in File.ReadAllLines(arquivo, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            Match action = regexAction.Match(linha);

            switch (action.Value)
            {
                case "InitGame":
                    game = InitGame();
                    games.ListGames.Add(game);
                    break;
                case "ClientConnect":
                    ClientConnect(game, linha);
                    break;   
                case "ClientUserinfoChanged":
                    ClientUserInfoChanged(game, linha);
                    break;

                case "Kill":
                    Kill(game, linha);
                    break;    
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return games;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `arquivo`? The error says it has an invalid path character.

Comment: Updated, the error occurred in first line.

Comment: What file path passed as `arquivo`? Invalid path character may occur when using invalid file path or that file itself containing directory/folder paths which is in invalid format (not escaped yet).

Answer (score 0):

I changed File.ReadLine for StringReader and works, thanks!

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(arquivo);
                while (true)
                {
                    string linha = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (linha != null)
                    {
                        Match action = regexAction.Match(linha);
                        switch (action.Value)
                        {

                            case "InitGame":
                                game = InitGame();
                                games.ListGames.Add(game);
                                break;

                            case "ClientConnect":
                                ClientConnect(game, linha);
                                break;

                            case "ClientUserinfoChanged":
                                ClientUserInfoChanged(game, linha);
                                break;

                            case "Kill":
                                Kill(game, linha);
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return games;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```